# How to organize design files in a large project?

Tags: adobexd

I'm working with a big and complex system which has hundreds of screens. The artboards don't fit into a single Adobe XD file so I have to create multiple files. What is the best way to brake down the scope and organize the XD files? By functionality / by clients / by user roles...?

Comment: Hi, there's a SE site about [project management](https://pm.stackexchange.com/) that maybe fits better for this question.

Comment: @Danielillo It's about organizing my work as a UX designer, not a Project Manager

Answer (score 1):

Could you elaborate what you mean by scope, by functionality etc?

In Adobe XD, you can organise your artboards by grouping your shares, text etc and convert them into Components. You can also publish them into the Library and import it to your main file.

I guess the major drawback of Adobe XD is it doesn't support multiple pages which is the major plus in Figma.

But again, Components in Document Assets and using Libraries may address that.

Answer (score 0):

I recently searched information about how improve my work file. I'm using Figma, and the left panel allows to structure the document by sections.

I don't know if the following article can help you:

- [Setting up our file structure in Figma](https://medium.com/zeelo-design/setting-up-our-file-structure-in-figma-cba74b46fba5)

Comment: Thanks. I know that Figma allows creating tabs to structure your file. Not so lucky with XD though :)

Answer (score -1):

Whatever works best for you and your team.
How is the workload distributed in your group? By functionality, clients, user roles? Teams/persons ideally have their areas, so that is a good starting point.

Comment: I'm the only designer in a company :)

Comment: Still, there is no universal best method. If nobody else is ever going to work with the structure, partition according to your way of thinking.

Comment: e.g. Iäd structure according to level and design concept but that may not work for you for any number of reasons.